# For what values of $a$ does the equation $\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}=a$ have no solution for $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The hint in the book tells me to solve $x$ in terms of $a$. Not too sure what this part is supposed to achieve besides telling me what $x$ is.

Anyways I arrive to answer with the following steps.

$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}=a$

I multiply both sides of the equation by $1+\frac{1}{x}$ and get:

$1 = a + \frac{a}{x}$

Multiply both sides by $x$ to isolate the desired variable.

$x = ax+a$

Now what? I have no idea what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can write $$x(1-a)=a$$ If $a=1$ we have $$x\times 0=1$$, which is impossible. For $a\neq 1$ we get $$x=\frac{a}{1-a}$$

Comment: Sorry, could you explain how you arrive at this? For example I have no idea what enables you to write it as the equation in the first instance. After rearranging for $a$ i get $\frac{x-a}{x}=a$

Comment: @Vocaloidas $$x = ax + a \implies x-ax =a \implies x(1-a) = a \implies x = \frac{a}{1-a}$$

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator of $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$$ by $x$!

Comment: So just to see if I understand this correctly. In these sort of problems you can just reduce the equation where you have $a$ on both sides, and setting it to multiplicative identity allows you to see whether there is solution for $x$?

Comment: And it must be $$x\neq 0$$!